# Ansible Tower Workflow Job Template

Tags: templates, variables, ansible, workflow, jobs

I have two Job Templates as part of my Workflow Job Template in Tower.

The first Job Template provisions a VM.  I want to gather a piece of information (MAC address) from the VM, and pass it to the next Job Template.

When the Job Templates are run independently, and I supply the required values through a survey, they work.

How do you pass data/variables/facts to a subsequent job template from previously run job templates in the workflow?

I've tried the set_fact module, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables from one playbook to another in the workflow. What you need is [set_stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflows.html).